# SQL access 2007 query error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression.”

Tags: sql

I'm trying to make a query in Access 2007, but it keeps giving me this error

```
Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
```

The query is

```
Dim SqlQuery As String = "UPDATE FullNameTable 
                          SET FirstName = '" & fname.Text & "', 
                              MiddleName = '" & mname.Text & "', 
                              LastName = '" & lname.Text & "' 
                          WHERE ID = '" & id & "'"
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Remove the quote in where condition and try WHERE ID = " & id

Comment: What are the datatypes of those fields in the database?

Comment: At a guess, I'd say your `ID` column is a number, and you're comparing it to a string (by putting quotes around it). Best thing to do is print out the query string once you've constructed it, and check that way.